# WPF DataGrid adds a column with the name of a class variable, unable to get contents of cells

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am writing a program that requires information provided in a grid-like format, with user specifying both the number of columns (that I call tracks for this purpose) and rows (that I call segments).

For that I employed one DataGrid that will have the number of columns (tracks) and 1 row, and each of these cells should hold the number of segments for each track. Once this information is provided, it will populate a second DataGrid with the number of columns and rows defined for each of them. This means the columns may have different number of rows.

See these 2 pictures from Excel to illustrate what I am after, where I first define the number of columns and add 1 row so the number of rows of the second grid can be specified:

[image]

And then I expect a second grid with the added rows, ready for further user input which is what I will use for further processing. I added borders just so you see that these are the usable cells for each track (CanUserAddRows is False in the XAML, so the user needs to specify the exact numbers in the 1st datagrid as they will guide my loops and I can't have empty cells).

[image]

Please check my minimum working sample, with XAML and C# codes below:

```xml
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="204*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="69*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="227*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="60"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="40*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="160*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Label Content="Number of tracks" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
        <TextBox x:Name="txt_tracks" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Width="50" Height="20"/>
        <Button x:Name="bt_settracks" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Content="Set tracks" Width="100" Height="20" Click="bt_settracks_Click"/>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgrid_tracks" CanUserAddRows="False"></DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>

        <Button x:Name="bt_setsegments" Content="Set segments" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Width="100" Height="20" Click="bt_setsegments_Click"/>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <DataGrid x:Name="dgrid_segments" CanUserAddRows="False"></DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public class dTracks
        {
            public ushort rowTracks { get; set; }
        }

        private void Create_Headers(DataGrid dgrid, ushort NUM_TRACKS)
        {
            dgrid.ItemsSource = null;
            dgrid.Columns.Clear();
            for (ushort i = 0; i < NUM_TRACKS; i++)
            {
                DataGridTextColumn newtrack = new DataGridTextColumn();
                newtrack.Header = "Track " + i.ToString();
                newtrack.Binding = new Binding("rowTracks");
                newtrack.IsReadOnly = false;
                newtrack.Width = 100;
                dgrid.Columns.Add(newtrack);
            }
        }

        private void Set_Tracks(DataGrid dgrid, ushort NUM_TRACKS)
        {
            Create_Headers(dgrid, NUM_TRACKS);
            ObservableCollection<dTracks> tracks = new ObservableCollection<dTracks>() { new dTracks() { rowTracks = 0 } };
            dgrid.ItemsSource = tracks;
        }

        private void Set_Segments(DataGrid dg_tracks, DataGrid dg_segments, ushort NUM_TRACKS)
        {
            Create_Headers(dg_segments, NUM_TRACKS);
            MessageBox.Show(dg_tracks.Columns.Count.ToString());
            MessageBox.Show(dg_tracks.Items.Count.ToString());
            for (int j = 0; j < dg_tracks.Columns.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dg_tracks.Items.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    String s = (dg_tracks.Items[i] as DataRowView).Row.ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(s);
                }
            }
        }

        private void bt_settracks_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Set_Tracks(dgrid_tracks, Convert.ToUInt16(txt_tracks.Text));

        private void bt_setsegments_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) => Set_Segments(dgrid_tracks, dgrid_segments, Convert.ToUInt16(txt_tracks.Text));
    }
}
```

When you run it, you will already see some problems:

- In the first DataGrid, it creates an additional column with the name of the variable in the class associated to the ObservableCollection;
- When you type the number of segments for each track, it applies to all cells instead of only the current cell;
- When you set the segments, the second DataGrid correctly shows the number of tracks you specified.

Along the function Set_Segments() I attempt to print some values just for debugging. The number of columns for the 1st DataGrid shows 1 more column then it should, and then I try to cycle through the cells to get their values and add them to the second DataGrid (to replicate the second picture), but these values are not coming and the MessageBox in the loop doesn't even come up with anything, not even an error.

Evidently there is something missing/wrong in the C# part, but so far I couldn't find any sample that considers different numbers of rows for each column, as most of the demos populate the datagrid with objects already in memory.

Maybe you guys can demonstrate how to solve those points mentioned above.

Comment: I think it will be simpler to use 5 (Verical) StackPanels (arranged horizontaly), and just add the required number of  TextBoxes to each stack. (Adding them to shadow collections based on need) You're creating an illusion. It doesn't have to reflect what's behind the scenes; which may not be suitable (i.e. the "collection").

Comment: @GerrySchmitz I agree with your simpler approach, and I originally thought of just using a grid to create as many of these boxes as necessary. I am really new to C# and just started 1 week ago, and after spending 24h just to figure out how to edit a cell in a datagrid, it is still pretty wrong in the "code behind", as people now call it. :) Even if I get past this part of individual cells having their own (manually entered) values, I don't know if it is possible at all to have columns with different number of rows.

Comment: Code-behind ist not wrong. The DataGrid is a row based table where each row consists of the same number of cells defined by the table's columns. If you need individual column "heights" the DataGrid is not the right control. You should consider to use a Grid as container that starts its content in columns. Then add a Listbox (or plain ItemsControl) to each column to host the rows. This way you can gracefully create dynamic views like your table-like view or like a Kanban board using DataTemplates.

Comment: DataGrid is row based, but you need a column based view like the mentioned Kanban board for instance.

Comment: For your first table view, I recommend a horizontally oriented ListBox. You can allow the user to add a column by person a button which actually results in adding a Track item to the ListBox. I will post a small example later.

Comment: @BionicCode Thanks for your feedback and apparently it goes in the direction of non-DataGrid approach like Gerry also suggests. With only a few days of experience in C# and WPF, I am really not aware of components "limitations". Then it is just better to come for counselling with the wiser guys. I appreciate your help.

Comment: I think you can still use the `DataGrid`. It would be good to use it because it supports column reordering. And because you can use i t with a DataTable as data source it could be more convenient to deal with. I will post an example. However, the first DataTable should be a horizontally oriented ListBox.

Comment: To me it is totally okay if I have to "reshape" the input data (which will be manually entered by user), now that I know that, if I want to use DataGrid, there are some "requirements", which I wasn't aware of. When you have time to post some guidance I will try it out.

Comment: What are those requirements that you have?

Comment: Apologies for not being clear. When I mentioned "requirements" I referred to the fact that DataGrid requires a row-oriented problem to be useful, while I was thinking column-oriented until you suggested horizontal listboxes. Sorry for not choosing the words properly. :)

Comment: What is the final purpose of this? Do you want to drag items from on column to another?

Comment: I will make a task planner for my managers that connects to our company's database and cross-check what they plan to do with backlog in the database (which I don't intend to write stuff to). I tried all stuff we have access to in Office 365, and after hearing much complaints from them, I foolishly offered to make something to easy their pain (at my expenses now). :)

Comment: That sounds like something that can easily get quite big very fast. I hope your estimations regarding effort are good enough otherwise you will end up with an unfinished project. It's not difficult especially if you don't support any interaction like drag&drop. It's reading data from the database and presenting it as it sounds. Doing in-house projects can escalate quickly as soon as you start to ask everybody for their personal wishes ;) In the end you find yourself developing Office 730 - alone :D I wish you success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to use a horizontally oriented `ListBox` for the configuration table (in place of the single-row `DataGrid`) and a `DataGrid` for the actual column view. For this view we have to deisable the cell and its borders to make it appear like a column-based `DataGrid`.
We basically fill a `DataTable` with `NULL` to mark a non-data cell:

| Track 0 | Track 1 |
| --- | --- |
| empty | empty |
| NULL | empty |
| NULL | empty |

All cells that contain a `null` value are not rendered. The advantage over using a simple `ListBox` per column is that you get the sort and reorder functionality of the `DataGrid` control.

The following example shows how you can achieve the desired visual presentation by using a value converter and defineing the `DataGrid.CellStyle`.

[Microsoft learn: Data binding overview (WPF .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-7.0)

[Microsoft learn: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window x:Name="Root">
  <StackPanel x:Name="RootPanel">

    <!-- Click to add a new column definition -->
    <Button Content="Add column"
            Click="OnCreateNewColumnDefinitionButtonClicked" />
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=TableColumnInfos, Mode=OneTime}">

      <!-- Change list box orientation to horizontal -->
      <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemsPanel>

      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:TableColumnInfo}">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
              <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition />
              <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
              
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" 
                       Grid.Column="0" 
                       Text="Column name:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.Column="1"
                     Text="{Binding ColumnName}" />
              
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
                       Grid.Column="0"
                       Text="Row count:" />
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1"
                     Grid.Column="1" 
                     Text="{Binding RowCount}" />
          </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

    <!-- Generate the table from the collected data -->
    <Button Content="Generate table"
            Click="OnGenerateTableButtonClicked" />

    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ColumnTable}"
              GridLinesVisibility="None"
              ColumnReordered="OnDataGridColumnReordered"
              CanUserAddRows="False">
      <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
          <Style.Resources>
            <local:CellBorderThicknessConverter x:Key="CellBorderThicknessConverter" />
          </Style.Resources>

          <!-- Remove the cell border and disable the cell if it is a non-data cell -->
          <Setter Property="BorderThickness">
            <Setter.Value>
              <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CellBorderThicknessConverter}"
                            ConverterParameter="1">
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}"
                          Path="Columns" />
                <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}" />
              </MultiBinding>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
          <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                  Value="Black" />
        </Style>
      </DataGrid.CellStyle>
    </DataGrid>
  </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public ObservableCollection<TableColumnInfo> TableColumnInfos { get; }

  public DataTable ColumnTable
  {
    get => (DataTable)GetValue(ColumnTableProperty);
    set => SetValue(ColumnTableProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ColumnTableProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "ColumnTable", 
    typeof(DataTable), 
    typeof(MainWindow), 
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.TableColumnInfos = new ObservableCollection<TableColumnInfo>();
  }

  private void OnGenerateTableButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    var dataTable = new DataTable();
    int maxRowCount = 0;
    foreach (TableColumnInfo columnInfo in this.TableColumnInfos)
    {
      var dataColumn = new DataColumn(columnInfo.ColumnName, typeof(string));
      dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);

      if (columnInfo.RowCount > maxRowCount)
      {
        maxRowCount = columnInfo.RowCount;
      }
    }

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < maxRowCount; rowIndex++)
    {
      DataRow row = dataTable.NewRow();
      for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < dataTable.Columns.Count; columnIndex++)
      {
        // Set cells that are non-data cells to NULL 
        // so that they are later disabled (invisible and disabled for user input)
        TableColumnInfo columnInfo = this.TableColumnInfos[columnIndex];
        string? cellValue = rowIndex >= columnInfo.RowCount 
          ? default 
          : string.Empty;
        row.SetField(columnIndex, cellValue);
      }

      dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    this.ColumnTable = dataTable;
  }

  private void OnDataGridColumnReordered(object sender, DataGridColumnEventArgs e)
  {
    var dataGrid = (DataGrid)sender;
    dataGrid.Items.Refresh();
  }

  private void OnCreateNewColumnDefinitionButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    => this.TableColumnInfos.Add(new TableColumnInfo());
}
```

**CellBorderThicknessConverter.cs**

```cs
public class CellBorderThicknessConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    DataGridCell dataGridCell = values
      .OfType<DataGridCell>()
      .First();
    IList<DataGridColumn> dataGridColumns = values
      .OfType<IList<DataGridColumn>>()
      .First();

    // Data source is not a DataTable 
    if (dataGridCell.DataContext is not DataRowView dataRowView)
    {
      if (dataGridCell.DataContext.ToString().Contains("NewItemPlaceholder"))
      {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
      }

      throw new NotSupportedException("Only DataTable supported");
    }

    double borderThickness = double.TryParse(parameter as string, out double thickness) ? thickness : 1;

    int columnDataIndex = dataGridColumns.IndexOf(dataGridCell.Column);
    int columnDisplayIndex = dataGridCell.Column.DisplayIndex;
    DataRow currentRow = dataRowView.Row;
    bool isCurrentCellVisible = IsCellVisible(columnDataIndex, currentRow);
    if (!isCurrentCellVisible)
    {
      // Collapse cell so that it is no longer editable
      dataGridCell.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

      // Remove the grid lines around this cell
      return new Thickness(0);
    }

    // The current cell is visible.
    // Next is to determine if we have to draw the left border and top border.
    // Left/top borders are only drawn if the previous cell/row is hidden
    // to prevent doubled lines. To know the state of the previous cell/row
    // we have to inspect their values.
    // The DataGrid differentiates between column dispaly index (user can rearrange columns)
    // and the real underlying data column index.
    bool isCurrentCellFirstColumn = columnDisplayIndex == 0;
    DataTable sourceTable = dataRowView.DataView.Table;
    int rowIndex = sourceTable.Rows.IndexOf(currentRow);
    bool isCurrentCellFirstRow = rowIndex == 0;
    double leftBorderThickness = borderThickness;
    double topBorderThickness = borderThickness;

    if (!isCurrentCellFirstColumn)
    {
      int previousDisplayColumnIndex = columnDisplayIndex - 1;
      int previousDataColumnIndex = GetDataColumnIndexFromDisplayColumnIndex(previousDisplayColumnIndex, dataGridColumns);
      bool isCurrentRowPreviousCellVisible = IsCellVisible(previousDataColumnIndex, currentRow);
      if (isCurrentRowPreviousCellVisible)
      {
        leftBorderThickness = 0;
      }
    }

    if (!isCurrentCellFirstRow)
    {
      int previousRowIndex = rowIndex - 1;
      DataRow previousRow = sourceTable.Rows[previousRowIndex];
      bool isPreviousRowCurrentCellVisible = IsCellVisible(columnDataIndex, previousRow);
      if (isPreviousRowCurrentCellVisible)
      {
        topBorderThickness = 0;
      }
    }

    return new Thickness(leftBorderThickness, topBorderThickness, borderThickness, borderThickness);
  }

  public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    => throw new NotSupportedException();

  private bool IsCellVisible(int columnIndex, DataRow dataRow)
  {
    object cellValue = dataRow[columnIndex];
    return cellValue != DBNull.Value && cellValue != default;
  }

  private int GetDataColumnIndexFromDisplayColumnIndex(int displayColumIndex, IList<DataGridColumn> columns)
  {
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columns.Count; columnIndex++)
    {
      DataGridColumn column = columns[columnIndex];
      if (column.DisplayIndex == displayColumIndex)
      {
        return columnIndex;
      }
    }

    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(displayColumIndex));
  }
}
```

**TableColumnInfo.cs**

```
public class TableColumnInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

  private int rowCount;
  public int RowCount
  {
    get => this.rowCount;
    set 
    { 
      this.rowCount = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  private string columnName;
  public string ColumnName
  {
    get => this.columnName;
    set
    {
      this.columnName = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    => this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Comment: I have just tried your suggestion in a sketch app and it is actually much more sophisticated than I originally intended, specially with the possibility to reorder the items. Thanks a lot for the brainstorming and this demonstration that puts me back on track.

Comment: I wonder if there was any dependency in the VS installation for your solution, because my company used VS019 until a few days ago, and now that it moved to 2022 maybe something is missing? There is no way I get the <TableColumnInfo> to be found. I even went to find out it mentioned in System.Management.Automation.dll but adding it to the projects references doesn't help. Sorry to resurrect closed topic.

Comment: `TableColumnInfo` is a custom type. I just missed posting the implementation. Sorry for the inconvenience. This must have been very annoying for you. Sorry! I have updated the answer.

Comment: It is me who has to apologize for not testing your entire solution in one go, as I was doing it little by little. And when it came to the TableColumnInfo it happened when our VS environment was updated, so I thought it stopped working because of that. It is now my job to connect everything and get rid of the "not found in namespace" errors of those 2 .cs files. :) Thanks for your kind assistance.

Comment: Oh, what namespace errors do you have? VS will usually add the usings for you. I think you can configure it in the settings that when you paste code VS will add the usings to the file. Let me know if you need help to fix it or to get the example working. Enjoy  your new IDE.

Comment: It is the "CellBorderThicknessConverter" and "TableColumnInfo" not found in my application's namespace (though both are surrounded by a "namespace MyApp { }", and the MainWindow that doesn't contain defintion of OnDataGridColumnReordered, so I am working on it. That's what I get for staying away from programming in Windows since Borland C++ Builder 6!!! :-)

Comment: Another one that is on me. I have renamed the event handler `OnDataGridColumnReordered` method in XAML but not in C#. It's the last method in MainWindow.xaml.cs. I have fixed the name. Maybe fixing this also fixes your other errors too as the code should now build properly. Maybe try a Clean + Rebuild after applying the renaming fix.

Comment: Wow, Borland C++. Back in the days... If a veteran like you mastered C++ you will handle C# for sure. ;)

Comment: Now I'm nostalgic. Kind amiss the MS DOS days. Had a lot of fun.

Comment: You are right that fixing the name of the method also gets rid of the namespace errors, and the only thing that seems left (if I can apologize again for testing things in small pieces and not the whole package at once), is that the button "Add Column" does not have its method "OnCreateNewColumnDefinitionButtonClicked" in the .cs. "Fortunately" I am on holiday and able to work on this the whole day.

Comment: I am having a blast with the amount of things I am learning from this one solution from you, specially after 20 years in Linux exclusively. I remember BCB 6.0 fondly because it gave me the best paychecks, in 2002-2003 it was either VB or Delphi that gave you a job, with BCB community considerably smaller. It was fun. :)

Comment: Upps. Usually I'm not that sloppy. Sorry again. I have added the OnCreateNewColumnDefinitionButtonClicked click event handler.

Comment: Funny. I have a colleague who is also maintaining some legacy application in Delphi. He is the last samurai of Delphi. The lone wolf. I mean it's good when you can in your special skills. That makes you very special for the company I guess. It's just a single line. Then enjoy your holidays. Don't make them workdays ;)

Comment: You solution is up and running. :) Maintaining legacy code generally commands good salaries, my friends working with COBOL are always happy. I see you hail from Deutschland, which I cross on motorcycle trips frequently, I hope we can drink a beer some day, mein Herr.

Comment: Haha, would be a pleasure sir :) I hope you had a good time here. Have good time ;)